# Invalid conversion from char * to int fpermissive

Tags: c++, pointers, char, int

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char** argv){
int n;
if(argc>1)
    n=argv[0];
int* stuff=new int[n];
vector<int> v(100000);
delete stuff;
return 0;
}
```

When I try to run this code snippet I got an error **invalid conversion from char * to int fpermissive**. I can not figure out what does this error indicate. If any one have any idea please help me to find out its meaning.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `n = argv[0]` is converting a `char *` to an `int`.    There are various functions in the standard library for converting strings to integral values.    Even with those functions, your code doesn't make sense - `argv[0]` will be a string that represents the name of your program, so converting it to an `int` doesn't make sense.       Also `delete stuff` should be `delete [] stuff` to avoid undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a `char*` pointer to an `int` variable, unless you type-cast it, which is not what you need in this situation.  You need to parse the `char*` string using a function that interprets the *content* of the string and returns a translated integer, such as [`std::atoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi), [`std::stoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), etc.

Also, you are not initializing `n` if the user runs your app without entering a command-line parameter.  And the first user-entered parameter is stored in `argv[1]`, `argv[0]` contains the calling app's path/filename instead.

Also, you need to use `delete[]` instead of `delete`.  Rule of thumb - use `new` and `delete` together, and `new[]` and `delete[]` together.  Or prefer to not use them directly at all (use `std::vector`, `std::make_unique<T[]>()`, etc instead).

Try something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char** argv){
    int n = 0; // <-- initialize your variables!
    if (argc > 1)
        n = atoi(argv[1]); // <-- [1] instead of [0]! and parse the string...
    int* stuff = new int[n];
    vector<int> v(100000);
    delete[] stuff; // <-- use delete[] instead of delete!
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

argv is a pointer to a pointer to a character which in short you can assume as pointer to strings and you assign an element of that directly to n.

n is a character array.
First convert n to an integer by atoi() which you can find in stdlib.h

I guess in C++ it is cstdlib.